# Timeout invocation on piped commands

Tags: bash

Could somebody explain how the `timeout` works for piped commands? For example,

```
timeout 2s a | b
```

Here is the `timeout` applied only for the `a` command?
 And if timeout indeed occurs, would that result in a broken pipe?

Comment: Yes, `timeout` is a regular command, not a built-in, so it is executed with arguments `timeout`, `2s` and `a`.  If the timeout occurs, the pipe for `b` will indicate EOF once all the data in it has been read (because there's no process left to write to the pipe).  But the broken pipe is a problem on the write side, not the read side.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thankyou, nice note on pipe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `timeout` is a regular command, not a built-in, so it is executed with arguments `timeout`, `2s` and `a`. If the timeout occurs, the read end of the pipe in `b` will indicate EOF once all the data in it has been read (because there's no process left to write to the pipe). But `b` will not get a SIGPIPE signal from `a` exiting (whether because of a timeout or because it finished before the timeout); a broken pipe is a problem on the write side, not the read side.